# osx version of gdb doesn't show leading underscore in object file

Tags: c, macos, gdb, name-mangling

In my Mac OSX 10.7, gdb (v. 6.3.50) can open an object file (say foo.o); gdb commands 'info functions' and 'disassemble' show the same names as in C source, but 'nm' command (nm foo.o) shows a leading underscore.

I tried 'set demangle-style none', 'set print demangle off', 'set print asm-demangle off' in gdb without success.

If I ask gcc to produce asm source (gcc -c foo.c) I can see that function names are decorated as shown by 'nm' command.
The same if I make a mistake calling a non existent function: when linking the object file (gcc foo.o -o foo.bin) I can see that function names are decorated.

How can I tell gdb to show the leading underscore?
Any help will be appreciated.

Also: If I move the obj file to a Linux distro, 'nm' prints: "File format not recognized".  I noticed it's not ELF: 'file foo.o' tells "Mach-0 64bit object x86_64".
How can I do to use that obj file in Linux?

Comment: To address only the last point, you _can't_ use object files compiled for Mac OS X with Linux. They use a different binary format (Mach-O) incompatible with ELF, and binary code for Mac OS X has a slightly different ABI. Forget about linking ELF and Mach-O together. And the reason your `nm` won't recognize it is because it was not built with Mach-O support enabled.

Comment: Thank you: I was thinking to have forgot some linker option.  I also noticed that I cannot move asm source (foo.s) to a Linux distro: when linking (gcc foo.s -o foo) I get assembler error messages like "character following name is not #" or "alignment not a power of 2".